# What is the right way to make transitions in titanium?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, titanium, transition

I can't figure out how to make transitions between views in titanium.

I have two views (maybe I should use different windows?) in two files.

ApplicationWindow.js

```
//Application Window Component Constructor
function ApplicationWindow() {
    //load component dependencies
    var FirstView = require('ui/common/FirstView');

    //create component instance
    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor:'#ffffff'
    });

    //construct UI
    var firstView = new FirstView();
    self.add(firstView);

    return self;
}
```

FirstView.js

```
//FirstView Component Constructor
function FirstView() {
    //create object instance, a parasitic subclass of Observable
    var self = Ti.UI.createView();

    var create_button = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title: L('create_game'),
        height:'auto',
        width:200,
        top:40,
        borderWidth:1
    });
    self.add(create_button);

    var join_button = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title: L('join_game'),
        height:'auto',
        width:200,
        top:80,
        borderWidth:1
    });

    self.add(join_button);

    var anim;

    create_button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var CreateGameView = require('ui/common/CreateGameView');
        var createGameView = new CreateGameView();
        createGameView.setLeft(640);
        self.parent.add(createGameView);
        anim = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
        left: -640,
        duration: 1000
        });
        self.animate(anim, function() {
            anim = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
            left: 0,
            duration: 1000
            });
            createGameView.animate(anim);
        });

    });

    join_button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        alert(e.source.text);
    });

    return self;
}

module.exports = FirstView;
```

CreateGameView.js

```
//CreateGameView Component Constructor
function CreateGameView() {
    //create object instance, a parasitic subclass of Observable
    var self = Ti.UI.createView();

    var start_button = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title: 'Pickles',
        height:'auto',
        width:200,
        top:40,
        borderWidth:1
    });
    self.add(start_button);

    var join_button = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title: L('join_game'),
        height:'auto',
        width:200,
        top:80,
        borderWidth:1
    });

    // Add behavior for UI
    join_button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        alert(e.source.text);
    });

    return self;
}

module.exports = CreateGameView;
```

This code doesn't really work.

help?

Comment: can you explain a bit what's going wrong.

Comment: @pronox you can try and run it.
the second view isn't visible after the animation.
if i manually set its left to 0 so it works but w/o animation.

Answer (score 0):

try to use different animation objects.

```
create_button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var CreateGameView = require('ui/common/CreateGameView');
        var createGameView = new CreateGameView();
        createGameView.left=640;
        self.parent.add(createGameView);
        anim = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
        left: -640,
        duration: 1000
        });
        self.animate(anim, function() {
            var anim1 = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
            left: 0,
            duration: 1000
            });
            createGameView.animate(anim1);
        });

    });
```

Comment: ok. i thought it should work if we use two different objects but anyway i tested code and come to know that you need to show 1 pixel of CreateGameView in window then this will work so try to set left of CreateGameView to 319 instead 640.

createGameView.setLeft(640);